# How to change default layout for ALL controllers in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How do I change the default layout globally (= for all controllers and views) in Yii2? I want to leave the main.php layout as is in case I want to use it later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In root of configuration you can write default layout [[[\yii\base\Application::$layout]](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$layout-detail)] for all views:

```
[
     ...
     'layout' => 'main',
     'components' => [
     ...
     ]
]
```

Comment: If I do this I get the following error: An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: yii\web\View::layout in C:\...\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:197

Answer (score 2):

Configure [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#layout) & [layoutPath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#layoutPath) in Yii2 config:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'layoutPath' => '@app/views/layouts2',
    'layout' => 'main2.php',
];
```

Above example changes default view `app/views/layouts/main.php` to `app/views/layouts2/main2.php`.

> [Yii2 Application Structure > Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do in the following way. For example a defaultLayout.php layout can be created like this:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/main.php'); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">Left Side Bar</div>

            <div id="content" class="col-lg-4">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div><!-- content -->

            <div class="col-lg-4">Right Side Bar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Inside the relative action

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'defaultLayout';

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' =>$model,
    ]);
}
```

In configuration(config/main.php) you can overwrite the default layout for all your views

```
[
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'layout' => 'main.php'
        ],
        // ...
    ],
]
```

Comment: The change to config/main.php is incorrect. See accepted answer for correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, you can edit the [layoutPath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#$layoutPath-detail) .

Example:

```
$config = [
    ...

    'layoutPath' => '@app/views/layouts-2'
];
```

Comment: ...but I want to specify a specific layout, not just the folder where they are located.

Comment: Just see the documentation link. With `layoutPath`, you can have your own layout for ALL controllers and actions and you will leave the default layout intact. (as you said in your question).

Comment: If that's not the case, please rewrite your question and be more clear on what you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Change in config/web.php file

and add this line before components array

your new style name which is created in view/layout/main_style.php

```
'layout' => 'main_style'
```

Using this whole project layout changed

Comment: Answer adds no new information compared to already accepted answer.